# Resource access in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, jar

I have a Spring boot web application (embedded Jetty Server). All the java code and resources are packaged inside a JAR and deployed on the server. However there is a JSON file outside the JAR but is in the class path. 
i.e.

> my classpath is : /usr/local/myserver/ 
>   the JSON file is at : /usr/local/myserver/hello.json 
>   the JAR is at : /usr/local/myserver/app.jar

When I hit the URL : https://IP:port/hello.json it gives me the "404 File not found".
The IP mentioned is the server on which all the files and JAR is present. I believe the default resource path is /static/.. which is inside the JAR. Any file in that 'static' directory is accessible.

I have configured:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/hello.json").addResourceLocations("file://localhost/usr/local/myserver/");
    }
```

How can I access the JSON file ?

Answer (score 0):

If the '`JSON`' file is already in `classpath` then why don't you use the `classpath:` prefix like

```
classpath:/usr/local/myserver/
```

if you use `file:/` prefix, then it loads the `JSON file` using URL class so basically you need to give absolute path location like

if it is windows

```
file:/usr/local/myserver
```

Comment: My classpath is : **/usr/local/myserver/**  and I have tried using **classpath:/** , it doesnt work.    Also in the code I wrote above, I have used the absolute location for the Linux server i.e. **file://localhost/usr/local/myserver/**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "file://" prefix + the absolute destination on your file system "/usr/local/myserver/".

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/hello.json")
        .addResourceLocations("file:///usr/local/myserver/");
```

Comment: Wow ! I had been trying a lot around this; and I remember trying the above Pattern before too, didnt work at that time. But somehow Now It Works !!! Thanks ..